# Understanding the Hiring assistant problem

Tags: probability-theory, algorithms, algorithmic-randomness

I am reading Introduction to Algorithms by CLRS and saw the probabilistic analysis of the Hiring assistant problem

> Problem : $n$ people appear randomly for a job interview for an
> assistant . We hire person $i$ if the person is better than all the
> persons before him i.e $0-(i-1)$ . Calculate the average number of
> times a new assistant is hired ?

The problem was solved using Random indicator variables given below :
[image]

Now from

\begin{align} E\left[ X\right] =\sum _{x=1}^{n}xP\left( X=x\right) \\=\sum _{i=1}^{n}E\left[ X_{i}\right] \\.  \end{align}

\begin{align} E\left[ X\right] =\sum _{i=1}^{n}i\cdot P\left( X=i\right) =\sum E\left[ X_{i}\right] \\=\sum _{i=1}^{n}\frac {1} {i}  \end{align}

Changing variable from \begin{align} x\rightarrow i  \end{align}

\begin{align} \Rightarrow \sum i\cdot P\left( x=i\right) =\sum i\cdot \frac {1} {i^{2}}\\\Rightarrow P\left( X=i\right) =\frac {1} {i^{2}}\\.  \end{align}
But \begin{align} \forall iP\left( X=i\right) =\frac {1} {i^{2}}\\,  \end{align} seems wrong

> Can someone explain :
>
> 1.How to calculate \begin{align} P\left( X=i\right) \exists i\leq n \end{align}
>
> 2.In the method given in Cormen can someone explain intuitively how the Expected value of $X$ is given by $ \sum _{i=1}^{n}P(i)$ . That is sum of probabilities of hiring candidate $i$
>
> 3.Also in a broader aspect what is the use of indicator random variables and how should they be used in problems

Comment: I don't see that  the expected value of $X$ is given by $ \sum _{i=1}^{n}P\left(X_{i}\right)$

Comment: Well correcting it

Comment: I´ve got it now. The third question is very general.

Comment: Well $E\left( X\right) =\sum E\left( X_{i}\right)$   but $E\left(X_{i}\right) =P\left( i\right)$ implies $E\left( X\right) =\sum P\left( i\right)$

Comment: Yes third one is general , just out of experience can you tell where it is used

Comment: I hope this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179961/intuition-behind-the-concept-of-indicator-random-variables) helps for the third question.